# Magento 2: How to display the category in product URL?

Tags: magento2, product, php, category

I want to get the product URL with categories in home page where I just load the product collection and used the `getProductUrl()` function.
But it returns only product URL key.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create an instance of  ObjectManager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Then, load the product by product id i.e., pass the `id` of the corresponding product

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
```

Now call the getProductUrl() function and it will return the URL of your product

```
echo $product->getProductUrl();
```

This method will return the URL of your product.

Comment: Yeah!! I did the same thing what you said! But I want the url with its category. Now it is returning only product url.